# FirebaseUI Dependency Conflict

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using FirebaseUI React Components (https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react) to implement FirebaseUI Auth in a React app, which has previously worked without any issues. However, I recently upgraded Firebase to v9, and now when I try to install FirebaseUI React Components I receive a dependency conflict. Specifically, when I try:

```
npm install --save react-firebaseui
```

I receive the error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: project-js-frontend@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: firebase@9.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/firebase
npm ERR!   firebase@"^9.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer firebase@"^8.2.4" from react-firebaseui@5.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-firebaseui
npm ERR!   react-firebaseui@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Has anyone else working with FirebaseUI React Components, or FirebaseUI more broadly, encountered this error and found a solution? According to the Firebase docs, v9 is not compatible with FirebaseUI, and the issue I am encountering may be related to the issue here (https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/837) - however, if that's the case, is there any way to make FirebaseUI work after upgrading Firebase to v9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to the Firebase docs, v9 is not compatible with FirebaseUI,
>
> ...
>
> is there any way to make FirebaseUI work after upgrading Firebase to v9?

If you want to be adventurous and try to get these things working together, you can start with `npm i --save firebaseui@next`. At the time of this writing, that will install `firebaseui@0.600.0` which is presumably a pre-release for `firebaseui@6` which is intended to add compatibility with `firebase@9`.

If you want to be *really* adventurous, you can try applying the change set at https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/pull/850, but that appears to be undergoing active development (comments as of 3 days ago). Perhaps it will be merged and released in the not-too-distant future and hopefully your issue will be resolved by it.

Comment: I tried to be adventurous (not REALLY, anyway :D) but still didn't work. I can replace `StyledFirebaseAuth` with a custom component, and also use the firebase sdk to open the popup (or redirect the user). What I don't understand is what output to produce as a result of the login so that I don't break `react-firebase-auth` pipeline.